# Why can't I take in a variable for title in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

In flutter you can't set the `title` variable to test because `Text` would not be constant.

```
class StockCard extends StatelessWidget {

  String test;

  StockCard(String t) {
    test = t;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (
      new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Card(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                title: Text(test), // ERROR: error: Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.
                subtitle: Text('Apple Incorporated'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

How would I achieve this and why does flutter not allow this to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because you try to instantiate the parent `ListTile` as `const`.

But for `ListTile` to be `const`, it requires its child `Text` to be const too, therefore cannot have a variable.
Just change `ListTile` to *not* be `const`:

```
ListTile(
   ...
)
```